# Many-to-many relationships in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a `Many-to-many` relationships between my tables `products`, `categories`, `filters`. My relations are defined like this:

**Product Model**

```js
public function categories() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category','products_categories');
}

public function filters() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Filter', 'products_filters');
}
```

**Category Model**

```js
public function products() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product','products_categories');
}
```

**Filter Model**

```js
public function products() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product','products_filters');
}
```

I'm trying to add a `where` clause on `products_filters` table to get `the products that have a category=$category`. What i did is the code below but it's not returning the correct values based on what i have on the DB:

```js
DB::table("products_filters")
    ->leftJoin('products','products.id','=','products_filters.product_id')
    ->leftJoin('products_categories','products_categories.product_id','=','products.id')
    ->leftJoin('categories','categories.id','=','products_categories.category_id')
    ->where('categories.target','=',$category)
    ->whereIn("filter_id", array_values($ids))
    ->pluck("products_filters.id")
    ->all();
```

Comment: Using `DB` to build raw queries will not use relationships at all

Comment: @BrianThompson how should i proceed ?

Comment: [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent) uses relationships.

Comment: @brombeer isn't there a way to get the result i want using raw queries ?

Comment: If you are using row queries you don`t use joins? what`s wrong with it?

Comment: When you say you're not getting the correct values, is that based on what you can see in the database? Or is it returning, nulls, no data, etc.?

Also, something to try, after the `whereIn()` add `->toSql()` and dump the result so you can check the full raw query.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `->all()` with `->get()`?